# What does it mean "HTML4 does not allow JavaScript to run within the web browser while HTML5 does"?

Tags: javascript, html

The comparison descriptions between HTML4 and HTML5 mention that HTML4 does not allow JavaScript to run within the web browser, but HTML5 provides full support for JavaScript to run in the background. What does it really mean?

According to my knowledge, the case is the following: HTML contains tag `<script>`, where the supported script sources can be placed. The standard itself does not need to care with the details, but in practice this means JavaScript only. On the other hand, if JavaScript can be really used or not, this is a setting of the browser: it can be enabled or disabled *on browser level*. But that has nothing to do with the standard.

So the questions is: technically speaking, what does it really mean that HTML4 does not allow JavaScript to run within the web browser, while HTML5 does?

Comment: What "comparison descriptions" are you referring to?

Comment: Can you provide the source of your "comparison descriptions" so that we know the context of the article/definition? Thanks.

Comment: I found it on several places, e.g. here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-html-and-html5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that **"HTML4 does not allow JavaScript to run within the web browser"** is pointing to the **Web Worker** concept which was introduced in HTML5.

in HTML4 when you execute scripts in an HTML page, the page becomes unresponsive until the script is finished. A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of the page. You can continue to do whatever you want: clicking, selecting things, etc., while the web worker runs in the background. ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp))

In fact Web Wrokers are running in a thread different than the window thread.

Read more about web worker [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).